# Angular - Check if firebase is logged in

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am very new to Angular and just getting used to how it all fits together. So I have a basic start to an app using Firebase for authentication. What I want to achieve is that I have a login component which works for logging in. But then in my header component for example, which is global and outside the router-outlet. I want to have something like this in the header component html template

```
<*ngIf="IsLoggedIn"logout-component></logout-component>
```

And what I would like to do is have a public variable, below

```
public IsLoggedIn: boolean = false;
```

then that is set to true if you get logged in separately, and then inject that service/ login component with the boolean into the header component, which means the logout component is show.

I have my login component, works fine.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  public error : any;

  constructor(public af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe( auth => {
      if(auth) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/members');
      }
    })
  }

  loginGoogle() {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Google,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup
    }).then(
      (success) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/members'])
      }
    ).catch(
      (err) => {
        this.error = err;
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Header component so far

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public angularfire: Angularfire) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to dynamically toggle a component based on the value of a Boolean which changes over time?

Comment: I want the logout component to show if the `IsLoggedIn` value is set to true, which set from another login component (should be a service) which is then injected into the header component?

Comment: You want to data bind to a computed value such as a function call expression, a getter, or an ambient observable